# How can I get a random username from my first array but check the second array

Tags: php

How can I get a random username from my first array, but the username selected shouldn't be in the "denied usernames Array" in PHP

```
Array of usernames
Array ( 
  [0] => stdClass Object ( [user_login] => emma88 ) 
  [1] => stdClass Object ( [user_login] => milli ) 
  [2] => stdClass Object ( [user_login] => publishers@a.com ) 
  [3] => stdClass Object ( [user_login] => shawn ) 
  [4] => stdClass Object ( [user_login] => shawnfao2 ) 
) 
2021-03-23
2021-03-23

denied usernames Array: 
Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( [username] => emma88 ) 
   [1] => Array ( [username] => milli ) 
   [2] => Array ( [username] => publishers@a.com ) 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For both `$valid` and `$invalid` users;

   - Use [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to get an array of all the `user_login`
2. Use [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to get all the users that are in `$validusers`, but not in `$invalidusers`
3. Use [`array_rand`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) to get a single index of the newly array

```php
<?php

    $valid = [ (Object) ['user_login' => 'emma88'], (Object) ['user_login' => 'milli'], (Object) ['user_login' => 'shawn'] ]; 
    $invalid = [ (Object) ['user_login' => 'emma88'] ]; 

    $validusers = array_column($valid, 'user_login');
    $invalidusers = array_column($invalid, 'user_login');

    $onlyvalidusers = array_diff($validusers, $invalidusers);

    $randIndex = array_rand($onlyvalidusers, 1);
    var_dump($onlyvalidusers[$randIndex]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY5BDoIwFET3nuIvTApJN@5IEF278gCkIZWC1LSlKYJy@grSKCDR@Jd/5s2MLrS1270u9GoF3a0bKjiDCGLwjqdLll59iFFdZSYR5ZkrBNEOUCYlDQJE8DeT5ELwH56qoDeFCJAQhnqu/hrwBEfDe1/VwdQY2iZpKWqpvEHCME7xw0nfMufED3JASyXaBZjxPPdGa/C0xBW7DEMVOyiW3V94//Fm2Rg2DmuoSVgt9dwRv5OIH1r7AA)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [array_filter](https://www.php.net/array_filter):

> Filters elements of an array using a callback function

Using an appropriate callback, you can create a list of users which are *not* in the denied list, e.g.

```php
$filteredUsers = array_filter($users, function($item) use ($denyList) {
    return ! in_array($item->user_login, $denyList);
}
```

You can use [array_column](https://www.php.net/array_column) to simplify the deny list array first.

You can then use [array_rand](https://www.php.net/array_rand) or [shuffle](https://www.php.net/shuffle) to pick one at random.